# What would this homebrew feature mean by applying multiple damage types to a single damage roll?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, damage-types

I want to play a homebrew mechromancer, specifically the one from [https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Mechromancer,*Variant*(5e_Class)](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Mechromancer,_Variant_(5e_Class)) and I was looking at the Misc. spell Core Burst. It says "On a failed save, the attacker simultaneously takes 1d8 fire, lightning, and force damage and half on a successful save." Does that mean it deals 1d8 that is typed with fire, lightning, and force or does it do a total of 3d8 damage with 1d8 fire, 1d8 lightning, and 1d8 force damage?

Comment: It's always good to see a new face! While your question could be answered by strict readings of the Homebrew, what it is isn't exactly Rules Legal so any answer given /could/ be against the spirit of the Homebrew. I suggest taking the [tour]

Answer (score 1):

**It would be 3d8 total, with 1d8 fire, 1d8 lightning, and 1d8 force.**

While this is a Homebrew and the wording is a bit weird, the 'simultaneously' kinda makes it harder to follow, the intention seems to be that the target would take all three of those at the same time but 1d8 of each. I can't think of an effect in 5e that lets you get hit with two elemental types in the same damage dice, how would resistance to fire work if you were hit by 'fire poison' for example? This isn't to say there aren't effects that let you hit with multiple damage types in the same spell or attack, using Meteor swarm to do fire and bludgeoning or a poisoned sword for slashing and poison, but it is to say that the wording is different than the regular. It should read something like **"A creature takes 1d8 fire, 1d8 lightning, and 1d8 force damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one"**

With that as the explanation I think it is clear by the designers intent for it to be 3d8 damage. I think the wording of simultaneously is so certain effects wouldn't add multiple times, like damage modifiers on certain spells or features.